# How to select * from table but distinct on 1 column and order by on another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a messages table with fields channel_number, body, created_at, recipeint_id & sender_id I want to have messages distinct on channel_number and order by messages.created_at

basically I want to show all channels in paginations and channels with latest message will be at top. This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
where id IN ( (SELECT channel_number, MIN(id) AS messages_id 
               FROM messages 
               GROUP BY channel_number
              ) as a
           ) a.messages_id 
ORDER BY a.messages_id DESC;
```

I have been working on this for a couple of hours and made many queries but it didn't work because in results I need all fields of message instead of selected channel and id.

Edits - I am using postgres and there is no uniq constrain on channle_number in messages table

Comment: Please include some sample data.

Comment: Are you running MySQL or Postgres? Please tag only the relevant database.

Comment: its postgres...

Comment: Do you want it ordered by created_at when deciding which row to keep for each channel_number, or do you went to pick which distinct rows some other way but then order the end result by channel_number?

Comment: I have given answer how I have done I think you will understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked good for me

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
where (channel_number, id) IN (select channel_number, MIN(id) AS last_message_id
                                FROM "messages"
                                WHERE (sender_id = 3 OR recipient_id =2)
                               )
GROUP BY "messages"."channel_number"
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL you can do:

```
select distinct on (channel_number) m.*
from messages m
order by channel_number, id desc;
```

You can also use correlated sub-query :

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.id = (select max(m1.id) from messages m1 where m1.channel_number = m.channel_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

select distinct column_1 from table order by column 2 asc/desc;